# Deploying rails app with realtime-rails gem and redis on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, socket.io

I have built a rails app following the model presented here:
http://mikeatlas.github.io/realtime-rails/

I am using Rails with the realtime-rails gem and redis.  My application is working in my development environment and i want to move it to Heroku.  I have already setup a Redis database at Redis-to-go and I now want to make whatever changes are necessary for the realtime-gem and associated socket-io server setup.  At a minimum, I will need to modify the production portion of my application_controller:

```
def realtime_server_url
    if Rails.env.development?
        return 'HTTPLOCALHOST:5001'
    end
    if Rails.env.production?
        return 'PRODUCION-LOCATION'
    end
end
```

I have deployed  the socket-io server (realtime-server) that is installed by instructions from the link above for realtime-server to a separate heroku instance. I then made the PRODUCION-LOCATION that url for the realtime -server dyno with port 5001 and both http and https. No joy.

Following the instructions the realtime-server folder was created at the top level of my project folder, parallel to the app folder. Does this mean i should include it in the main repository and somehow have it run from the same dyno as the app? If so, how do i go about starting it? The instructions say to start it by locally with:

```
 cd realtime-server
 foreman start
```

Not clear that I can do that through the heroku cli will be able to run in the same instance and how is it started.

=============

## Update

Found documentation on heroku that made me realize,   I need to set the REDISCLOUD_URL for the heroku dyno running the realtime-server using:

```
heroku config:add REDISCLOUD_URL='redis_cloud_url'
```

and that in production it wasnt using the 5001 port:

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
        port = 5001; // run on a different port when in non-production mode.
    }
```

Also, found form console log that the realtime-server was enforcing HTTPS.

Now, the blocking issue seems to be the request of /socket.io/socket.io.js from the realtime-server which returns:

```
503 (Service Unavailable)
```

So far, it seems that separating the realtime-server from the rails app repository was the right move.

Looking through the code for the realtime-server to determine how that is routed...

================

## Update

i looked at the logs on your advice, thanks. saw that the realtime-server  was crashing because it wasnt  liking the port, so I tried to set the PORT variable  443, 3000, 5001 variously to no avail  using:

```
heroku config:add PORT='443'
```

based on this code from the enviornment.js file of the realtime-server:

```
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
        port = 5001; // run on a different port when in non-production mode.
    }
```

here is an excerpt of logs:

```
      2015-02-22T19:26:45.512317+00:00 heroku[api]: Set PORT config vars by tmt@breakthroughtek.com
      2015-02-22T19:26:45.512317+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by tmt@breakthroughtek.com
      2015-02-22T19:26:45.754327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
      2015-02-22T19:26:48.318928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node forever.js`
      2015-02-22T19:26:49.540190+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
      2015-02-22T19:26:49.540213+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      2015-02-22T19:26:49.957808+00:00 app[web.1]: STARTING ON PORT: 5001
      2015-02-22T19:27:44.163425+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by tmt@breakthroughtek.com
      2015-02-22T19:27:48.811493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
      2015-02-22T19:27:48.811551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
      2015-02-22T19:27:49.561043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
      2015-02-22T19:27:49.561720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
      2015-02-22T19:27:49.534451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
      2015-02-22T19:27:51.936860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node forever.js`
      2015-02-22T19:27:53.289025+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
      2015-02-22T19:27:53.289046+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      2015-02-22T19:27:53.703573+00:00 app[web.1]: STARTING ON PORT: 5001
      2015-02-22T19:28:51.991836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
      2015-02-22T19:28:51.991836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
      2015-02-22T19:28:52.758191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
      2015-02-22T19:28:52.764783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
      2015-02-22T19:31:22.240362+00:00 heroku[api]: Set PORT config vars by tmt@breakthroughtek.com
      2015-02-22T19:31:22.240362+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by tmt@breakthroughtek.com
      2015-02-22T19:31:22.378770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
      2015-02-22T19:31:24.766187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node forever.js`
      2015-02-22T19:31:26.316332+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
      2015-02-22T19:31:26.316353+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      2015-02-22T19:31:26.717561+00:00 app[web.1]: STARTING ON PORT: 5001
```

===========

## Update

looking at the logs and seeing the system was still picking port 5001, I checked the heroku environement via :

```
heroku config
```

and saw that the NODE_ENV variable was not set. Did a:

```
heroku config:add NODE_ENV='production'
```

and now the js file is loading.  YAY!!! .. Thanks, d.danailov :)

Have to resolve some issue with rails on heroku erring with a missing template error on access to the admin area:

```
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.492199+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LocationsController#index as HTML
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497052+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497054+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497059+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:8:in `index'
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497050+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template locations/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497062+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497057+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-02-22T20:04:36.497056+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/realtime-0.0.12/app/views"
```

And of course, the page is working fine in development. So I am going to start with the assumption it has something to do with sprockets/asset pipeline.

But i think this portion may be solved. I will close once I verify I can send realtime msgs.

=============

## Update

SOLVED: beware you dont use redis elsewhere in your app. 
HEADS UP: i had a sneaky little Redis.new in an initializer that was wiping out my Redis config settings.

Comment: Can you give more details ? Please type ```heroku logs```

Comment: I hope my update helps but here is the code for the node.js realtime-server [link](https://github.com/mikeatlas/realtime-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the solution was setting the NODE_ENV & REDISCLOUD_URL vars for the realitme server running in a separate instance.